# 7z a folder in chunks of 100MB and decompress

Tags: linux, command-line, 7-zip

I am trying to 7z a folder (in chunks of 100MB) and add it to archive in Linux. Is the following command correct?

```
tar cf - dir/ | 7z a -v100m -si dir.tar.7z
```

How can I decompress the folder? I have tried the following command, but it is not working:

```
7z x -so dir.tar.7z | tar xf
```

Comment: You have to be more specific that "doesn't work"

Answer (score 1):

On my Linux system, your compression command produces files called dir.tar.7z.001, dir.tar.7z.002, etc., but no .7z file. That means your command to decompress the tar file will not work, as you are specifying a file which does not exist. Instead of:

```
7z x -so dir.tar.7z
```

try:

```
7z x -so dir.tar.7z.001
```

Additionally, you are using the wrong tar arguments to uncompress from stdin. Instead of:

```
tar xf
```

use just:

```
tar x
```

In summary:

```
7z x -so dir.tar.7z.001 | tar x
```